# Open specific facebook page from Android app on Amazon platform

Tags: facebook-page

Below codes have been being working on Android devices.

```
    final String url = "fb://page/" + PublishInfo.getFacebookID();
```

But Not works on my kindle fire. It triggered facebook application only.

Is there additional code instead of?